# Electron browser versus isolated context changes Buffer to UInt8Array and breaks my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm upgrading an Electron App, now using preload/isolated context over browser chromium runtime and I've stumbled over a strange problem with Buffer.
I'm using an external javascript npm package; osc-min which makes some test using Buffer.isBuffer(...) internally several places to ensure valid arguments have been passed.

But calling from Electron preload script I now see that all my code creating the buffers now returns UInt8Arrays instead of old plain 'Buffer' type.
When I debug the code in chromium console i can see that the Buffer.isBuffer now fails on testing an argument of UInt8Array type.

If I test Buffer.isBuffer(Buffer.from('123')) I get 'true'.
If I test Buffer.isBuffer(UInt8Array.from('123')) I get 'false'.

I have tried many things to provide a 'Buffer' type but it ends up as a UInt8Array which does not validate in Buffer.isBuffer(.. no matter what when debugging inside the library in the isolated context.

Any suggestions what to do in this case would be highly appreciated, thanks